# Y-axis title partly disappears when downloading graph image in Highcharts

Tags: image, download, highcharts

I've put the y-title for my charts on the top of the y-axis. In all graphs, it looks alright. But when I want to export the graph as an (png, jpeg) image, the y-axis title get's dislocated and partly chopped off. [Here](http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/bafu/bevoelkerung_ch.php?lang=de) is an example of the graph, and this is the printed result:

[image]

Thanks for any hints how this could be solved. I guess it's a default on the Highcharts server side programming, as it seems to contact always the export.highcharts.com server when generating the images...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use subtitle, instead of rotated yAxis label.

http://jsfiddle.net/VVv2J/

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#subtitle.align

```
subtitle: {
        text: '* Footnote aligned right',
        align: 'left'
    },
```